# Infra-Pták space that is not Pták

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

From reading the literature of the 1970s heyday of locally convex spaces, it seems that it was an important open question whether there is an infra-Pták (i.e. $B_r$-complete) space that is not Pták (i.e. $B$-complete). Is this still open?

Comment: Could you please recall the definitions? I would first check to book *Barrelled Locally Convex Spaces* of Bonet and Perez-Carreras.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Thanks for the book reference. I hadn't seen it before, but it looks like it contains a lot of the harder-to-find later results of the Iberian school of TVS theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valdivia constructed counterexamples in his paper [Br-Complete Spaces which are not B-Complete](https://eudml.org/doc/173399).